# Java Apache POI writing Double value in Cell (german Excel)

Tags: java, format, apache-poi, separator

i have a problem. When i am writing a double value (say 20.3) in an excel cell and specify a format ("0.0") the "german" Excel does not recognize the value as a number, because in Germany the separator for decimal numbers is a comma, not a point. For example the "english" number 1,000.00 would be 1.000,00

I tried it with a DateFormat like "0,0", but excel still thinks the value is a string.

I need the value to be a number, because of formulas.
And: The clients of my software use Excel with german number format. There is no dicussion about it :(

Is there a way to say POI to write a double value "the german" way?
Or is there any workaround for this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be a problem because in POI the `setCellValue(double)` method is overridden for `double` and thus independent of locale settings. It looks like you are using `setCellValue(String)` or `setCellValue(RichTextString)`. Correct that and it should work.

If that doesn't work for you, you have to post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use as data format `General`. You can use that for Integer or Double values.

```
CellStyle cellStyle = cell.getCellStyle();          cellStyle.setDataFormat(workbook.getCreationHelper().createDataFormat().getFormat("General"));
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
cell.setCellValue(1.678);
```